# Mensaje de error al compilar un arreglo de struct como atributo

Tags: c++

No sé cómo crear un atributo del tipo arreglo de struct. Les dejo mis codigos, me da este error:

En classAntena.h dice 'celulares' was not declared in this scope.
En classAntena.cpp dice 'Celulares' does not name a type.

classAntena.h

```
#ifndef CLASSANTENA_H_
#define CLASSANTENA_H_


class Antena{

private:
    Celular celulares[100];

public:
    void incrementarLlamadasRealizadas(int);
    void incrementarLlamadasRecibidas(int);
    void incrementarDuracionLlamadas(int,int);
    void modificarInicioLlamada(int,int);
    void modificarFinLlamada(int,int);
    int devolverLlamadasRealizadas(int);
    int devolverLlamadasRecibidas(int);
    int devolverDuracionLlamadas(int);
    int devolverNumeroCelular(int);

};

#endif /* CLASSANTENA_H_ */
```

---

classAntena.cpp

```
#include "classAntena.h"

struct Celular{

    int numeroCelular;
    int cantLlamadasRealizadas;
    int cantLlamadasRecibidas;
    int duracionLlamadas;
    int inicioLlamada;
    int finLlamada;
};

void Antena::incrementarLlamadasRealizadas(int posCel){

    celulares[posCel].cantLlamadasRealizadas++;
}

void Antena::incrementarLlamadasRecibidas(int posCel){

    celulares[posCel].cantLlamadasRecibidas++;
}

void Antena::incrementarDuracionLlamadas(int duracionLlamada, int posCel){

    celulares[posCel].duracionLlamadas += duracionLlamada;
}

void Antena::modificarInicioLlamada(int comienzoDeLlamada, int posCel){

    celulares[posCel].inicioLlamada = comienzoDeLlamada;
}   

void Antena::modificarFinLlamada(int finDeLlamada, int posCel){

    celulares[posCel].finLlamada = finDeLlamada;
    int duracionLlamada = celulares[posCel].finLlamada - celulares[posCel].inicioLlamada;
    incrementarDuracionLlamadas(duracionLlamada, posCel);
}

int Antena::devolverLlamadasRealizadas(int posCel){

    return celulares[posCel].cantLlamadasRealizadas;
}

int Antena::devolverLlamadasRecibidas(int posCel){

    return celulares[posCel].cantLlamadasRecibidas;
}

int Antena::devolverDuracionLlamadas(int posCel){

    return celulares[posCel].duracionLlamadas;
}

int Antena::devolverNumeroCelular(int posCel){

    return celulares[posCel].numeroCelular;
}
```

Comment: ¿No será porque has declarado el campo como un solo struct en lugar de un arreglo? Es decir: tienes el campo `Celular celulares` cuando debería ser `Celular celulares[]`. Y en el constructor de la clase deberías inicializar el valor del arreglo y la cantidad de elementos en dicho arreglo.

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta pero aun no entiendo, ya probe de mil formas. Puse Celular celulares[100] y tampoco funciono.

Comment: Adicionalmente, creo que el struct debería estar definido en el h, no en el cpp. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para mostrar el mensaje de error que aparece al intentar compilar el código?

Comment: ya lo edite gracias.

Comment: Sí, tal como pensaba, debes mover la declaración de `struct Celular` a tu archivo .h y debe estar declarado antes de la clase, de manera que se pueda reconocer.

Comment: si ! graciaaas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. La definición de `struct Celular` debe estar en el archivo .h antes de la definición de la clase. De lo contrario, el compilador no puede saber qué es `Celular`.
2. En tu clase `Antena` el campo está definido para soportar 1 solo elemento, no es un arreglo. Cambia la declaración para que sea un arreglo:

   ```
   Celular celulares[];
   ```